# VHDL declaration expression cannot contain relational operator?

Tags: vhdl, ghdl

I try to code a counter with a range from a to b that could be flipped top to bottom when the two generic parameters a and b fulfill a>b. Whether flipping occurs could be determined at compile time by comparing the values and setting a constant to hold the result (used later in the logic). However, the comparison fails. I have distilled the following minimal failing code example:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity test is
end entity test;

architecture b_test of test is
begin
    process
            constant t : bit := 3 < 7;
    begin
            wait;
    end process;
end architecture b_test;
```

`ghdl analyze` complains about the line with the constant declaration:

> no function declarations for operator "<"

The same error is reported if instead a constant, a variable is declared like

```
variable t : bit := 1 < 3;
```

How can I precompute a `bit` typed variable based on comparison of integer values a and b (actually a and b would be generic paramters of a subtype integer range)?

Comment: The message tells you there's no integer less than relational operator defined that returns a value of type bit instead of the expected type boolean. You could [write a conversion routine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEa7r.jpg). (There are simpler conversion routines than shown, including an in line expression).

Comment: Because boolean and bit have the same number of enumeration values you can take the position  (predefined attribute 'pos) of one to produce the value (predefined attribute 'val) of the other: `constant t: bit := bit'val(boolean'pos(3 < 7));` The function would only require a return statement - `return bit'val(boolean'pos(b));`

Comment: The standard requires relational operator overloads return a boolean and one that returns a bit value wouldn't be synthesis eligible.

Answer (score 0):

The constant should be defined with type `boolean`:

```
constant t : boolean := 3 < 7;
```

Relational operators return that type, see e.g.:

- [https://edg.uchicago.edu/~tang/VHDLref.pdf#page=106](https://edg.uchicago.edu/%7Etang/VHDLref.pdf#page=106)
- http://www.pldworld.com/_hdl/2/_ref/vhdl_lrm/1076_7.HTM#7.2.2

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to assign a variable (or constant) of type `bit` from that `boolean`. To the best of my knowledge (at least up to and including VHDL-2008), there is no standard VHDL function for converting from `boolean` to `bit`. Therefore, it is typical to write your own function.